# SQL Dense and Spare Indexes

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, database, indexing

I am preparing for my Database final and I would like to understand these two questions. Could you please explain to me which is the correct answer and why it is correct.

1. Suppose that you have a relation with the schema R(X, Y, Z). Every value of X is unique, but the
   other columns could have duplicate values. Assume that a **sparse** index is created for relation R on attribute **X**. Which of the following queries would use this index effectively?

   (a) SELECT MAX(X)
   FROM R

   (b) SELECT MAX(Y)
   FROM R
   GROUP BY X

   (c) SELECT *
   FROM R 
   WHERE X <> 30

   (d) SELECT MAX(Y)
   FROM R
   WHERE X = 23

   (e) none of the above uses the index effectively

I believe (a) could be the correct answer as we have an index for X and they are all unique values.

2. Suppose that you have a relation with the schema R(X, Y, Z). Every value of X is unique, but the
   other columns could have duplicate values. Assume that a **dense** index is created for relation R on attributes **X and Y**. Which of the following queries would use this index effectively?

   (a) SELECT *
   FROM R
   WHERE X < Y

   (b) SELECT DISTINCT X, Y
   FROM R
   WHERE X = 23 AND Y > 39

   (c) SELECT X, Y
   FROM R

   (d) SELECT X
   FROM R
   WHERE Y = 23

   (e) none of the above uses the index effectively

I believe (c) could be the correct answer as we have an indexes for both X and Y.

Comment: SQL Server or MySQL? They are very different.

Comment: @DaleK MySQL should suffice. We have used MySQL and SQL Server in the course, the professor did not specify in the question which exactly.

Comment: You might do better in the dba forum; I have to confess, i don't even understand the question

Answer (score 0):

MySQL does not have "dense" vs "sparse".  Here are the optimal indexes:

```
(a) SELECT MAX(X) FROM R   -- INDEX(X)

(b) SELECT MAX(Y) FROM R GROUP BY X   -- INDEX(x,y); INDEX(x) is not as good

(c) SELECT * FROM R WHERE X <> 30   -- No index is _likely_ to be useful

(d) SELECT MAX(Y) FROM R WHERE X = 23   -- Does not make sense if X is unique

(e) none of the above uses the index effectively  -- Some:  a,b,d
```

and

```
(a) SELECT * FROM R WHERE X < Y   -- no index

(b) SELECT DISTINCT X, Y FROM R WHERE X = 23 AND Y > 39  -- Dumb due to uniqueness

(c) SELECT X, Y FROM R  -- no index; just read the table

(d) SELECT X FROM R WHERE Y = 23   -- INDEX(Y,X), or, not as good, INDEX(Y)

(e) none of the above uses the index effectively  -- ambiguous; note that (Y,X) is not same as (X,Y)
```